Plotly graph value reading issues and hover data issues
I would like the percentage values to change as I move from year to year. Also, for some reason the value reading does not change eventhough it should be death rate per 100,000, instead of number of deaths.


decades = [1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
cols = ['Number of Deaths', 'Death Rate Per 100,000']
per= ['Number of Deaths pct change', 'Death Rate Per 100,000 pct change']
figs = []
frames = []

for c, color, p in zip(cols, ["Blues", 'Reds'], per):
    fig = px.choropleth(
        data_frame=Global_Burden_of_Disease_df_country,
        locations='Country Name',
        locationmode='country names',
        color=c,
        hover_name="Country Name",
        hover_data=p,
        animation_frame="Year",
        projection="equirectangular",
        color_continuous_scale=color,
    )
    fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title=c)
    figs.append(fig)
    
    for frame in fig.frames:
        frame['name'] = f"{c}_{frame['name']}"
        frames.append(frame)

layout = {
    k: v
    for k, v in figs[0].to_dict()["layout"].items()
    if k not in ["template", "updatemenus"]
}

fig = go.Figure(data=figs[0].data, layout=layout)
fig.frames = frames

frames_dict = {c: [f for f in frames if f['name'].startswith(c)] for c in cols}

dropdown_buttons = [
    {
        "label": c,
        "method": "animate",
        "args": [
            [f"{c}_{year}" for year in Global_Burden_of_Disease_df_country['Year'].unique()],
            {
                "mode": "immediate",
                "frame": {"duration": 500, "redraw": True},
                "transition": {"duration": 0},
            }
        ],
    }
    for c in cols
]

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": dropdown_buttons,
            "direction": "down",
            "showactive": True,
        }
    ],
    coloraxis_colorbar_title=cols[0],  
    title={"text": f"World map of {cols[:]} in {decades}"}, 
)

fig.show()


I tried messing with my code, but it resulted in ther percentage hover name to remain at zero.
I am abit confused about how I would change the value reading name, as I am new to plotly.
